# Possível criação de um fórum

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Existe alguma possibilidade da criação de algum fórum? Para ser discutido coisas mais baseadas em opiniões?

Hoje, aqui, é mais perguntas e respostas diretas/técnicas. Algumas outras coisas que as pessoas tem dúvidas, mas não precisam daquela resposta técnica, não podem ser discutidas aqui.

Então, um fórum talvez seja um local apropriado pra isso. É possível?

Comment: Tem um grupo de usuários no redit para discussões que não cabem no SOpt.

Comment: O que seria isso @rray?

Comment: Pode dr um exemplo do que teria nesse fórum?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/

Comment: @bigown Esse fórum iria servir pra discutir sobre códigos, práticas, opiniões, mercado de trabalho em T.i, experiência. Coisas que não podemos nos aprofundar tanto aqui. Exemplo tipo um Club do Hardware, mas, questões relacionadas a programação.

Comment: Essa descrição é um pouco ampla, vaga, se é pra fazer pergunta objetiva dá pra fazer, para discutir não fica bom. Exceto pelo opinião que não quer dizer nada, o resto pode, se a pergunta for bem feita.

Comment: Fórum na SE não, pelo amor de Java.

Comment: Só um comentário, se fóruns abertos a opiniões fossem bons eles seriam um sucesso maior que o Q&A do SOen :)

Comment: Talvez não ser melhor, mas as vezes, forum, num local, de tamanhã qualidade igual ao SOpt, poderia ajudar com dúvidas mais específicas, com opiniões, etc.. No meu caso por exemplo, eu acho bacana um fórum. Mas quem sou eu rs

Comment: Oras, tem o [chat]. Lá discutimos assuntos ontopic, offtopic, e dentro do limite do respeito mútuo, até zoeirice :p

Comment: Normalmente usam o chat para simular o que se faz em foruns. Mas por que não entra em foruns de verdade? No Brasil tem o iMasters que é o maior da América latina. Tem quase o triplo de membros que aqui e um rico e vasto conteúdo. https://forum.imasters.com.br

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, Daniel!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não é possível, o foco da rede não é provocar discussões. Já foi falado várias vezes sobre isso na rede. Claro que pode-se tentar mais um vez, mas não acho que vai rolar. Até mesmo os sites de Q&A do [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) já estão sendo criados de forma bem mais parcimoniosa.

É possível perguntar o que não é tão técnica assim, mas precisa estar clara, estar no foco do site e não pode ser pura opinião. Idealmente deve ajudar várias pessoas.

Existem outras ferramentas e locais fora da rede que pode-se discutir algo. Raramente gerará qualidade.

Comment: No caso, o que está dizendo é, que se for algo discutível e baseado em opinião, pode não ter qualidade?

Comment: Em geral não tem, vira Facebook. Não que precisaria ser assim, mas quase sempre acaba sendo. Pra não descambar teria que ter extrema moderação, aí vai se gastar mais tempo discutindo o autoritarismo dos moderadores que o assunto.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelas respostas, @bigown

Comment: @LucasCarvalho a opinião vale o que vale... O importante são os factos para que você possa gerar a sua própria opinião. Se toda a gente lhe der uma opinião como você saberá qual é a melhor? Só com os factos que estão por detrás dessas opiniões é que você poderá ter a sua opinião.